# problema con onBackPressed fragment android

Tags: android

Tengo un Navigation Drawer el cual instancia fragmentos, el problema que tengo, es que al presionar el botón atrás, el método onBackPressed muestre un alertDialog, pero al entrar a uno de estos fragmentos, al presionar el botón atrás me muestra el alertDialog y no vuelve al activity, y me pregunto como podría realizar la condición para solucionar el problema

```
 import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Valorar.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Reportar.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

        GoogleMap map;
        MapView mapView;
        int i;
        /**
         * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
         * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
         */
        private GoogleApiClient client;


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mapView.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mapView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.MapaPrincipal);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            map = mapView.getMap();
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            //safe map build
            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(this);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                //start point
            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-33.485309,-70.7067445));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);
            map.moveCamera(center);
            map.animateCamera(zoom);

            //if start point fail
            onMapReady(map);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                     .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar)
                     .setTitle("Cerrar Aplicación")
                     .setMessage("Deseas cerrar CicloMapp?")
                     .setCancelable(true)
                     .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                     {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             finish();
                         }

                     })
                     .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                     .show();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            boolean FragmentTransaction = false;
            Fragment fragment = null;

            if (id == R.id.AgregarRuta) {

            } else if (id == R.id.ValorarRuta) {
                fragment = new Valorar();
                FragmentTransaction=true;

            } else if (id == R.id.ReportarRuta) {
                fragment = new Reportar();
                FragmentTransaction = true;

            } else if (id == R.id.Eventos) {

            } else if (id == R.id.Refresco) {

            } else if (id == R.id.Leyes) {

            }
            if(FragmentTransaction){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                item.setChecked(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
            }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-33.485309,-70.7067445));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);
            map.moveCamera(center);
            map.animateCamera(zoom);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

        }
    }
```

PD: agrego el código

Comment: Agrega tu codigo por favor zhet!

Comment: pense que bastaba con la pregunta, he ahí el código

Comment: Es importante dar la mayor cantidad de datos posibles. De hecho no entiendo cual es el problema deseas no se muestre el dialogo? Cuando desees se muestre el dialogo?

Comment: cuando abro un fragmento quiero que me devuelva a la activity, pero no hace eso, muestra el alertDialog y no se devuelve, quiero que solo aparesca cuando estoy en la activity

Comment: Agrego una respuesta y comentarios en código.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una variable para determinar cuando se realizo una transacción que es `FragmentTransaction` la cual puedes usar para realizar la validación.

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            //Si el menú esta abierto, lo cierra.
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            //Si se realizo una transacción ejecuta onBackPressed();
            } else if( FragmentTransaction ){
             //   FragmentTransaction = false;
                super.onBackPressed();
            //muestra el Dialogo, no hay fragmento y el menú esta cerrado.
            }else{
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                     .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar)
                     .setTitle("Cerrar Aplicación")
                     .setMessage("Deseas cerrar CicloMapp?")
                     .setCancelable(true)
                     .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                     {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             finish();
                         }

                     })
                     .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                     .show();
           }
        }
```

Comment: funciono parcialmente, al entrar a algún fragmento, me devuelve a la activity pero al presionar el botón en la activity no muestra el AlertDialog, simplemente se cierra

Comment: si apreto el botón al iniciar la activity el mensaje aparece, pero si abro un fragmento, lo cierro y vuelvo a presionar en la activity, el mensaje no aparece

Comment: Agregue : FragmentTransaction = false; y trata nuevamente.

Comment: no funciono, quedo igual que como empeze, creo que despues de la primera condicion, no vuelve a preguntar

Comment: aun no logro solucionar el problema :(

Comment: @Zhet lograste solucionar tu problema ya que también tengo el mismo detalle.